# How fast can you fly with a Legion Flight Ring?

Tags: dc

The Legion of Super Heroes, in the 31st century, give their members flight rings. These rings enable all of their members to fly, whether they have that innate power or not. The ring allows them to fly in an atmosphere or in outer space.

**How fast does it enable someone to fly?**

Comment: At [the Speed of Plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot), of course.

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Legion_Flight_Ring Says that the rings are similar to Green Lantern Power Rings and activated by will power so it's plausible that the will of the user has a direct affect on the ring's speed.

Comment: @geewhiz I read that to mean that flying is a matter of thinking about it, rather than activating something mechanical.

Comment: @JackBNimble simply thinking about flying could be incredibly inconvenient. A legionnaire could be out for a walk and an errant though about flight could activate the ring. That's why it seems like they make the distinction between will and thought. Besides, according to http://www.comicvine.com/legion-flight-ring/4055-47353/ Dream Girl is able to make other objects fly due to the strength of her will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of flight, as enabled by the rings, is probably never established with specificity, but it is canonical that it is less than *super speed*.

This was revealed in an old *Legion of the Superheroes* comic book (probably from the period in the 1970s when Wildfire was the leader of the group). 
 Several members of the Legion were fighting some villains.  As the battle on the ground went against the villains, several of the baddies flew away, and Ultra-Boy followed in pursuit.  However, the villains got away by leaving the atmosphere, so that Ultra-Boy (who has a wide variety of powers, but can only use one at a time) had to give up the chase.  He states explicitly that he could not keep up with them without using *super speed*, but he could not survive in space without using *invulnerability*.  His Legion flight ring gave him flight powers at all times, but it was not fast enough to keep up without additional *super speed*.